# Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.(Error in MS-SQL)

Tags: sql, database, datetime, bigint, qsqltablemodel

**My code-**

```
SELECT dbo.NumericSamplesDelByTapan.TagID, dbo.Tags.TagName, dbo.Tags.Location
,(SELECT  DATEADD(Millisecond, FLOOR((dbo.NumericSamplesDelByTapan.SampleDateTime - 599266080000000000) % (10000000 * 60) / 10000)
, DATEADD(Minute, FLOOR((dbo.NumericSamplesDelByTapan.SampleDateTime - 599266080000000000) / (10000000 * 60) + 330), '01-01-1900')) AS EXPR1) AS TimeStamp
, dbo.NumericSamplesDelByTapan.SampleValue

FROM  dbo.Tags 
INNER JOIN dbo.NumericSamplesDelByTapan 
  ON dbo.Tags.ID = dbo.NumericSamplesDelByTapan.TagID
```

Comment: tag RDBMS correctly. MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,.....

Comment: What is the type of `dbo.NumericSamplesDelByTapan.SampleDateTime`? Why all these calculation? What are you trying to achieve in this Query? What exactly is the error message you are getting? Can you share some sample values from `dbo.NumericSamplesDelByTapan.SampleDateTime` ?